# joining multiple parts of a g element to the same data in d3

Tags: d3.js, transition

I am trying to figure out how to transition paths and text bound to the same data within a g element.

[This gist](http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewStaroscik/5139366) shows the behavior I want. When you click the change button the path and text positions transition smoothly. The problem is I accomplish this by separately joining the path and text elements to the data.  [I am not the only one using join this way](http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html), but I think it violates the goal of maintaining one to one mapping between elements and data with d3.

Is there a way to emulate the

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
     .data(dataset);

path
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values) + "Z"; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

path
    .transition().duration(500)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values) + "Z"; });

path
    .exit().remove();
```

pattern for elements linked to the same data within a g element?

[Here is one of my failed attempts](http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewStaroscik/5139474). Rather than updating the paths and text, the change button causes new g elements to be added.

Added on edit: failed attempt now works after correcting the typo found by explunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your class name on the join. This code:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".shapes")
    .data(dataset);
```

Should be this:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".shape")
    .data(dataset);
```

When I change it as above it works fine for me.